# Preencher form com extensão para google chrome

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma extensão que preenche um form de uma determinada página web, mas estou com um problema, o código não executa nem automaticamente e nem ao clicar em cima da extensão, estou muito perdido.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "SGIR - Extensão",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Preencher formulários",
"browser_action": {
    "script": ["funcao.js"]
},
"permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

funcao.js

```
chrome.window.onload = function(){
var ni = document.getElementById("NI");
ni.action = "Alguma coisa!";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há dois erros:

1. A key **[browser_action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action)** não possui o script, apenas *browser_style*, *default_icon*, *default_title*, *default_popup*, *theme_icons*.
2. O arquivo está chamando o método onload, depois da página já está carregada.

Para executar um código ao clicar no ícone da extensão, é necessário chamar um html de pop.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "SGIR - Extensão",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Preencher formulários",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "https://www.google.com.br/"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["funcao.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.google.com.br/"]
    }]
}
```

**funcao.js**

```
var ni = document.getElementById("lst-ib");
ni.value = "Alguma coisa!";
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="funcao2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**funcao2.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab[0].id, {
        "file": "funcao.js"
    });
})
```

Adicione a permissão à URL que você quer modificar. Pode ser regex.

Comment: Entendi sua explicação, mas mesmo assim, quando clico no icone da extensão nada acontece na página que estou, ele não completa o form, no caso o campo texto com id="NI", o que pode estar errado?

Comment: No caso de inputs, o correto é `ni.value = "Alguma coisa!";`.

Comment: Tentei com "value" também, mas nada acontece na página, ele apenas abre o popup da extensão...

Comment: @netoschneider Editei minha resposta. Dessa forma irá funcionar tanto automaticamente, quanto clicando no ícone da extensão.

Comment: Muito obrigado, sanou minha dúvida!